# Multiple background color in pChart

Tags: php, pchart

How to fill the multiple color in the pChart background. For example at the x-axis I want the background of 1-30 is red, 31-60 is blue and 61-90 is green(something like that) Is pChart has a function to do this kind of background or is it has some technique to do it.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the drawThresholdArea() function to do so. [See the doc here](http://wiki.pchart.net/doc.doc.draw.thresholdarea.html)